# Finding a mother vertex using DFS

Tags: c++, graph, depth-first-search

Given a Directed Graph, find a Mother Vertex in the Graph (if present).
A Mother Vertex is a vertex through which we can reach all the other vertices of the Graph.

Here is the caller function

```
int findMotherVertex(int V, vector<int>adj[])
{
    int count = 0;
        
    for(int i=0; i<V; i++){
        vector<bool> vis(V, 0);
        dfs(i, adj, vis, count);
            
        if(count == V){
           return i;
        }
        else{
            count = 0;
        }
    }
        
    return -1;
}
```

why this dfs function gives TLE(Time Limit Exceeded) on [GeeksForGeeks](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/mother-vertex/1)?

```
void dfs(int u, vector<int> adj[], vector<bool> &vis, int &count){
    vis[u] = 1;
    
    for(int v : adj[u]){
        if(!vis[v]){
            dfs(v, adj, vis, count);
        }
    }
    count++;
}
```

And this dfs function doesn't?

```
void dfs(int u, vector<int> adj[], vector<bool> &vis, int &count){
    vis[u] = 1;
    count++;
    
    for(int v : adj[u]){
        if(!vis[v]){
            dfs(v, adj, vis, count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you have something like `if( count==XXX )return;`  before `for` loop in the function `dfs`. (If not, you don't need the `count`.)

Comment: Why this strange mix of std::vector and a "C" style array?  `vector<int> adj[]`, model it as `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` for more consistency.  Note competitive coding is NOT a good way to learn C++.

Comment: what is TLE ? time limit exceeded? What is the time limit? who calls this function? What are the constraints on the input?

Comment: Have you actually timed it yourself for a large case? If so, show details. BTW, I assume that ```count``` was actually initialised somewhere and that adj[] actually has the requisite size. Basically, you haven't shown enough detail of your surrounding code.

Comment: BTW, this seems like a bit of an inefficient way to find a "Mother Vertex" anyway. If you apply this to different ```u``` then you will be repeating an awful lot of calculations.

Answer (score 0):

A "mother" node exists if and only if your graph is a single tree.  Usually this node is called the root of the tree.

Algorithm to check that a graph is a single tree and find the root:

- SET R NULL
- SET found false
- LOOP N over nodes

  - IF N has in-degree 0

    - IF found is true
      STOP "graph is not a single tree"
    - SET found true
    - SET R to N
- IF FOUND is false

  - STOP "graph is not a single tree"
- STOP "graph is single tree with root R"

It is impossible to be much more specific because your question lacks so many details ( that is why it is getting downvoted ).  But, notice that all you care about is the indegree of the nodes.  So, when scanning the input do not bother with an adjacency matrix or any of the usual graph data structure.  All you need is two vectors, one for the node IDs and one for the node indegree. When you find a new node, add it to the vectors.  When you find a new link, increment the target node's indegree vector.